# Errors when using fetch() in vanillajs, why?

Tags: javascript, request, fetch, response

I have this error :

```
TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
```

when I tried to fetch data from a server. and I don't know why...

My code :

```
getListApps: async function () {
             let url = `${SA_BASE_URL}/applications`;

            // Set headers
            let headers = new Headers();
            headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
            headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
            headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
            headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(SA_LOGIN + ":" + SA_PASSWORD));

            try {
                // GET request
                const response = await fetch(url, { method: 'GET', headers: headers, mode: 'no-cors' });
                if (response.ok) {
                    const data = await response.json();
                    this.listApp = data;
                    this.listApp.forEach(app => {
                        if (app.status === "DISCONNECTED") {
                            this.listDecApp.push(app);
                        }
                    });
                    this.nbr = this.listDecApp.length;
                } else {
                    if (response.status === 400) this.errors = ['Invalid app_permissions value'];
                    if (response.status === 401) this.errors = ['Acces denied'];
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
                this.errors = ["Une erreur est survenue lors de la récupération des informations sur le serveur."]
            }
}
```

On Firefox and chrome and I don't have any cors plugin anywhere.

Comment: What does the network tab say about this request?

Comment: I have that : NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI

Comment: It suggests that `url` is something invalid.

Comment: YOU are not allowed to set CORS headers on your client. It is the TARGET that sets those headers. These are not yours to set `headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
            headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
            headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);`

Comment: I'm sure the uri is valid. Normally it's supposed to return a 401 @VLAZ

Comment: @mplungjan ok I change it. But that's change anything if they are present, no ?

Comment: You will need to load the URL in the browser and see if it allows CORS. If not you  are SOL.

Comment: @mplungjan it's only my customer who can try in his browser because the remote server is private... Usually, he use Postman for doing his request and he can get the data

Comment: You can use Postman where you cannot use Browser

Comment: @mplungjan exactly... My custemr can send request with postman and he get the right data without problem. But with this function, that doesn't work...

Comment: If I understand correctly, it is the remote server that must be configured to accept browser requests ?

Comment: So the answer: You canot use a browser to access that server since they are not setting the access control

Comment: @mplungjan ok thanks ! ;)